# Ajax not returnig values to html when php variables are different from zero

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to create a mini shopping cart info box about how many items are in the cart and the total price. The code below works when the variables are zero, but when something is added in the cart they won't show and I can't figure out:why?

php function:

```
function a1() {
    $num=0;
    $pric3=0;
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $num=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty) {
                $query = 'SELECT price FROM proizvod WHERE id=' . $id;
                $result = $this->db->query($query);
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    $pric=$qty*$row['price'];
                    $pric3=$pric3 +$pric;
                    $pric=0;
                }          
            }     
        }

          $a = array(
              'num' =>$num,
              'price'=>$pric3);

        $json = json_encode($a);
        echo $json;
    }
}
```

and my ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',         
        success: function (data) {           
            $("#miniQty").html(data.num);
            $("#miniPrice").html(data.price);   
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#miniQty").html("");
            $("#miniPrice").html("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);`. Also, are you sure your query is correct? Try a `var_dump($row);` within your inner `foreach` loop to see what each row is (if anything).

Comment: Also check .. $num & $pric3 Is they have simple value or array something .?

Comment: check if there are any mysql_errors

Comment: Already checked that all. The items are inserted in the cart properly, things are passed with json format: {"num":1,"price":99} (i copyed the function,renamed it and called it without passing to js)

Comment: alse @SyedOsama they are simple values